# How to get all elements and send them as an array in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

in my shopping cart my code produces a structure like below every time based on  user's choice. every **tr**  is for a product and **x** indicates different value based on product and **id** is the id of product.So x,id and number of trs every time differ.

```
<tr>
    <td><span class="product-id" value="x"></span></td>
    <td><img class="product-img" value="x" /></td>
    <td><a class="product-name" value="x"></a></td>
    <td><span class=product-color value="x"></span>
    <td><select  class="qnty-id" value="x"></select></td>
    <td><span class="price-id" value="x"></span></td>
    <td><span class="total-id" value="x"></span></td>
</tr>
```

I want to collect them in an array  or Json format like this:

```
array(x => array(
    'id'=>'product-id',
    'name'=>'product-name',
    'color'=>'product-color',
    'quntity'=>'qnty-x',
    'price'=>'price-x',
    'total'=>'total-x')
)
```

And send them to my server side using Ajax.
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy Would you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering your table id as **table**, try this:

```
var table = $('#table');
var elems = table.find('tr');
var cartArray = [];
elems.each(function (i, item) {
    var itemSelector = $(item);
    var id = itemSelector.find('.product-id').attr('value');
    var img = itemSelector.find('.product-img').attr('value');
    var name = itemSelector.find('.product-name').attr('value');
    var color = itemSelector.find('.product-color').attr('value');
    var quantity = itemSelector.find('.qnty-id').val();
    var price = itemSelector.find('.price-id').text();
    var total = itemSelector.find('.total-id').text();
    cartArray.push({id: id, img: img, name: name, color: color, quantity: quantity, price: price, total: total});
});
console.log(cartArray);
```

Comment: You need to test it under different circumstances, It must work as code iterated all the rows of the table..

Comment: Thanks it worked with a bit change, but now  when I pass the array using Ajax I don't get a appropriate result in server side

Comment: @Mahdi Younesi, I am unable to understand the issue. You need to send JSON to the server not the javascript array...